# Send email with false email on PHP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, send

I installed recently PHPMailer, because of not being able to send without it.
Now I have another problem: I want to send an email with an invent one, for example, "no-reply@my-domain.com". I don't seem to be able to do it. when I send with Sendmail, it just won't send, and if I use SMTP with autentication, it sends with my email.

```
require "../PhpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "marcelo43@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "My Password";
$mail->setFrom('no-reply@my-domain.com','MyDomain Admin');
$mail->addAddress('to@gmail.com','To');
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->msgHTML('My message');
if(!$mail->send())
    echo 'Could not send email';
else
    echo 'Email succesfully sent';
```

This just sends an email to "to@gmail.com" with "MyDomain Admin" as the name and "marcelo43@gmail.com" as its email.
What do I need to do to send with the email "no-reply@my-domain.com"?

Comment: The mail server can enforce a from mail address. Since it does not change, I would either contact the server administrator or if you're that, look into the mail server config (`php.ini` also contains mail settings, check it too).

Answer (score 0):

You can't send email with a false email because Gmail blocks mail from an other domain that its own.
If you want to send an e-mail with an other domain you should use an other SMTP server. You can use an SMTP from OVH for example if you have a mail server. Otherwise, Yahoo will let you send you e-mail I think.

Comment: Where should I put Yahoo? On the host, username or what?

Comment: You should have a Yahoo account, and put Yahoo (smtp.mail.yahoo.com) on the host, with your login/password. The same as you are doing with Gmail, but with Yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail doesn't let you use arbitrary from addresses at all, even from gmail domains. You can however create aliases within your gmail settings that are allowed as from addresses. If you want to use your own domain via gmail, you will neeed to configure gmail as the MX for your domain. If you do that, you will be able to do what you ask.

BTW, this is mentioned in the PHPMailer docs.

Comment: What is MX? How can I do that?

Comment: `MX` is the short name for "mail exchanger" and refers to the entries in your DNS which tell senders which server(s) will accept mail sent to your domain. If google is handling your domain, google's mail servers will be in your DNS MX records.